# Import and Export using a complex name with ES2015

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Using node unit, I want to translate from ES5 the name of the test suite.

So I had in `parser_test.js`

```
exports['Awesome Parser Test'] = {
  setUp: function(done) {
    done();
  },
   ....
}
```

And now I have in `parser_test.es6`

```
export default {
  setUp: function(done) {
    done();
  },
   ....
}
```

Then in another file named `index.es6`

```
import parserTest from './parser_test';

export {       
    parserTest
}
```

Node unit displays the suite name as **parserTest** which is OK, but I would prefer something like **Awesome Parser Test**

Comment: Are you sure you mean ["traduce"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/traduce)?

Comment: `Awesome Parser Test` isn't complex, it's just syntactically incorrect name for a variable.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have spaces in the import name. It's just a variable which is assigned the export of the file. You can, however, call it what ever you want. Eg:

`import awesomeParserTest from './parser_test';`

Or

`import Awesome_Parser_Test from './parser_test';`